# LongAccumulator does not get a right result

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-8

Code first:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.LongAccumulator;
import java.util.function.LongBinaryOperator;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

/**
 * Created by tom on 17-4-13.
 */
public class ForSOF {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        LongBinaryOperator op = (v, y) -> (v*2 + y);
        LongAccumulator accumulator = new LongAccumulator(op, 1L);

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        IntStream.range(0, 10)
                .forEach(i -> executor.submit(() -> accumulator.accumulate(i)));

        stop(executor);

        // 2539 expected, however result does not always be! I had got 2037 before.
        System.out.println(accumulator.getThenReset());
    }

    /**
     * codes for stop the executor, it's insignificant for my issue.
     */
    public static void stop(ExecutorService executor) {
        try {
            executor.shutdown();
            executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("termination interrupted");
        }
        finally {
            if (!executor.isTerminated()) {
                System.err.println("killing non-finished tasks");
            }
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
}
```

Those above are whole codes what I crash about testing LongAccumulator class of Java 8. Codes from blog [winterbe.com](http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/05/22/java8-concurrency-tutorial-atomic-concurrent-map-examples/) with nice tourist articles about java8.

As API document said, method of those class in package `java.util.concurrent.atomic` will be atomic and thread-safe. However result was certainly when I run those above. Some time erorr with 2037 or 1244. There must be something wrong.

When I rewrite the first line inside main body to this:

```
LongBinaryOperator op = (v, y) -> (v + y);
```

It works in right way.

So, I guess that when JVM get v and double it, other thread had interrupt and get a same value of v, compute op expression and give a result which be rewrite by pre thread soon. That's why expre v+y works.

If anywhere of those codes should be improved?
Or a bug of LongAccumulator class?
I'm not sure.

---

God! What the logic of those code should be this:

```
public void test(){
    int v = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        v = x(v, i);
    }
    System.out.println(v);
}

int x(int v, int y){
    return v*2+y;
}
```

and output of v is 2037.

so what confuse me must be the disorder of computing stream.

Comment: Or disorder of stream makes results different?

Comment: Not quite sure what your problem is, you may want to rephrase it. But there goes: operation `x + y` does not depend on order of elements that get processed - if you instead do `y + x`, the result will be the same. `2x + y`, on the other hand, does depend on order of operands - `2y + x` is clearly not the same thing.

Comment: I run this code. When your stop method call's `shutdownNow()` all tasks in queue will be terminated and some accumulates won't be called.

Comment: Now. Depending on what you _actually_ want to do: if you want to say `[0..10] map (x -> x*2) collect(sum)` - you may want to change your accumulating operation: in `(v,x) -> v * 2 + x` the `v` operand is not the element in stream - it's the sum you collected so far. chagning it to `(v,x) -> v + 2*x` will make it have consistent result because you'll multiply operands, not the sum.

Comment: Also what others said - while you claim that termination doesn't affect what happens - it totally does. Especially the `shutdownNow()` - just wait for it to complete normally.

Comment: Why do you expect `2539` when the most common result would be `2037`, i.e. when the numbers 0..9 are applied in order? But, more importantly, when running each "apply" in separate threads, they can be applied in arbitrary order, and [`LongAccumulator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAccumulator.html) doesn't guarantee ordering, so only [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) functions should be used, and **`v*2 + y` is not commutative**. Example: apply the numbers in reverse order, i.e. 9,8,...,1,0 and you get `9218`.

Comment: @Andreas yes, arbitrary order makes the result uncertain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update: The problem described below has been accepted as a bug: [JDK-8178956](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8178956)*

Since this is a question about whether [`LongAccumulator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAccumulator.html) is buggy, I'd like to point out that it is, or perhaps rather that the documentation might be wrong.

First, though, the documentation clearly states:

> The order of accumulation within or across threads is not guaranteed and cannot be depended upon, so this class is only applicable to functions for which the order of accumulation does not matter.

The function used in the question (`(v, y) -> (v*2 + y)`) clearly violates that, since the order of calls to `accumulate()` matters.

To put it more in math form, if we accumulate two values, `a1` and `a2`, the documentation clearly states that the result can be either of these:

```
result = f( f(identity, a1), a2)
result = f( f(identity, a2), a1)
```

The documentation also states:

> The supplied accumulator function should be side-effect-free, since it may be re-applied when attempted updates fail due to contention among threads.

Which simply means that `f(identity, a1)` may be call twice, but the result of one of the calls will be discarded. Or that both `f(identity, a1)` and `f(identity, a2)` are called, but only one of them is used like shown above, and the other is discarded.

But, the documentation then says:

> The function is applied with the current value as its first argument, and the given update as the second argument.

Which is what is shown above, however that is **wrong**, because the result may also be calculated like this, in clear violation of that last statement:

```
result = f( identity, f(a1, a2) )
```

where the first argument to the inner call is *not* the "current value" of the accumulator, and the second argument to the outer call is *not* the "given update" value.

To see this, I modified the question code to this:

```
LongBinaryOperator op = (v, y) -> {
    try { Thread.sleep(200); } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
    long result = (v + y);
    System.out.printf("f(%d, %d) = %d%n", v, y, result);
    return result;
};
LongAccumulator accumulator = new LongAccumulator(op, 1L);

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

Arrays.asList(2, 3, 5, 11, 17, 23, 29, 37, 41, 47).stream()
        .forEach(i -> executor.submit(() -> accumulator.accumulate(i)));

executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

System.out.println(accumulator.getThenReset());
```

Running it produced this result (result varies on every execution):

```
f(1, 3) = 4
f(1, 2) = 3
f(2, 11) = 13
f(4, 5) = 9
f(13, 17) = 30
f(23, 29) = 52
f(30, 37) = 67
f(52, 41) = 93
f(67, 47) = 114
f(9, 93) = 102
f(102, 114) = 216
216
```

To show how the function is called to calculate the result, I'll annotate it by applying names to the values, i.e. `id` for initial identity value of `1`, `a0` to `a9` for the accumulate (input) values, and `r1` to `r11` for the function results. Note that `r2` is discarded, which is why there are 11 calls with only 10 values.

```
f(  1 id ,   3 a1) =   4 R1
f(  1 id ,   2 a0) =   3 R2  // result discarded
f(  2 a0 ,  11 a3) =  13 R3  // both arguments are input values
f(  4 R1 ,   5 a2) =   9 R4
f( 13 R3 ,  17 a4) =  30 R5
f( 23 a5 ,  29 a6) =  52 R6  // both arguments are input values
f( 30 R5 ,  37 a7) =  67 R7
f( 52 R6 ,  41 a8) =  93 R8
f( 67 R7 ,  47 a9) = 114 R9
f(  9 R4 ,  93 R8) = 102 R10  // both arguments are result value
f(102 R10, 114 R9) = 216 R11  // both arguments are result value
```

Answer (score 5):

> As API document said, method of those class in package java.util.concurrent.atomic will be atomic and thread-safe. However result was certainly when I run those above. Some time error with 2037 or 1244. There must be something wrong.

The [`LongAccumulator` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAccumulator.html) provide one important piece of information about this.

> The order of accumulation within or across threads is not guaranteed and cannot be depended upon, so this class is only applicable to functions for which the order of accumulation does not matter.

Your problem is that `v * 2 + y` operation is [noncommutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).  If you mix the order of the operations, you can get a wide variety of output.  The reason why `v + y` works is that you can apply that in any order and get the same result.

To break it out into serial code, you are effectively doing:

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (long i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    list.add(i);
}
// if you uncomment this, you get varying results
// Collections.shuffle(list);
long total = 1;
for (Long i : list) {
    total = total * 2 + i;
}
System.out.println(total);
```

The in-order result is 2037 but if you uncomment the `Collections.shuffle(...)` then you will see that the result varies with a max of 9218 resulting when the numbers are in reverse order.

Comment: you are absolutely right. `LongAccumulator` is like `AtomicLong`, but much better and faster is high concurrent environments.

Comment: @Eugene: but accumulating ten values can never be considered highly concurrent and with an accumulator function that will start overflowing with 63 elements (if not earlier), this is unlikely to be ever part of a highly concurrent environment.

Comment: @Holger exactly. My point with this was to Gray's: `I'm not a Java8 expert`... I just wanted to show why there was a need to introduce this to jdk-8. i don't know if I made that clear enough

Comment: @Eugene: I’m not objecting your comment, just augmenting it. You are correctly saying that this is a tool for highly concurrent environments and I’m just adding that the is unlikely the OP’s case, i.e. the OP is using the wrong tool for the job, whatever the OP’s job is…

Comment: @Holger it's actually insanely crazy beautiful how the implementation of that `LongAcumulator` is. I've spent quite a few days understating those details (which I don't remember right now if full glory unfortunately)...

Answer (score -1):

You have to change your code as shown below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LongBinaryOperator op = (v, y) -> (v + 2*y);
    LongAccumulator accumulator = new LongAccumulator(op, 1L);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    IntStream.range(0, 100)
            .mapToObj(val -> executor.submit(() -> accumulator.accumulate(val)))
            .forEach(future -> { while (!future.isDone()); });
    executor.shutdown();
    System.out.println(accumulator.get());
}
```

First it makes `op` execution order independent, because `v` represents the sum of already calculated values and `y` the value of your `IntStream` for which to calculate the new value `2*y`:

```
LongBinaryOperator op = (v, y) -> (v + 2*y);
```

Second you have to wait for each submitted task to finish, which can be detected by inspecting the returned `Future`:

```
forEach(future -> { while (!future.isDone()); });
```

Now it should work stable.

Comment: Your solution will still display inconsistent results, since still the `sum` is multiplied by two, which will affect the total. If I unwrap the computation: `2 * (2 * (2* 1 + 0) + 1) + 2 = 8`, and `2 * (2 * (2* 1 + 2) + 1) + 0 = 18`

Comment: Both `v*2 + y` and `v + 2*y` are *side-effect-free* functions. A *side-effect* would be something like the function adding `y` to a `List`, which should not be done, because the function may be called multiple times with the same `y` value. The difference between the two, is that the second is [*commutative*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), while the first is not, i.e. the order of applying the function doesn't matter.